# Making sequential network requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a two HTTP requests to make:

1. https://site.com/data/json/transactionref; and
2. https://site.com/data/json/processrequest/

I want it in such a way that **1.** must finish before processing **2.** because the **2.** needs the value of **1.** to continue.

How would I achieve this in Objective-C (and GCD)? I have check many tutorials here on stack overflow, but am still unclear.

FYI, I am using AFNetworking.

Comment: Why not make the 2nd request in the completion handler of the 1st request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AF..Operation since they are `NSOperation` Subclass you can add a dependency between the two
`[networkingOperation1 addDependency:networkingOperation2]`;
Then add them to the network queue.
If you are using `AFSessionManager` you should use a `dispatch_group`. Substantially you build a group of network tasks that triggers a specific block once they are done. [Here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) more info